# Is there a word for "the object of the infimum" (i.e., what the integrand is to an integral)

Tags: notation, terminology, supremum-and-infimum

As the title says, the mathematical expression which is the input to the integral is called the "integrand". Is there a comparable term for the infimum? (and/or supremum). That is, what would I call this term?

$$
\inf_{x \in S}\left\{ \underbrace{f(x) + g(x) }_{???} \right\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The '-nd' suffix of the words integrand, summand, multiplicand etc is the gerund form, meaning "that which is to be integrated/summed/multiplied/etc". As such, there may be a case for the words infimand and supremand for these two functions, but presently they are not words.

Personally, I'd define $f$ and $g$ first and then that "we take the infimum of their sum".